# Можно ли отследить работу алгоритма Work Stealing в OpenMP?

Tags: c++, openmp

Можно ли на примере какой-либо входной программы отслеживать работу алгоритма Work Stealing для OpenMP? Можно ли собирать статистику его работы? Есть ли какие-либо инструменты для этого?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Непонятно, что Вы имеете в виду.  В спецификации OpenMP нет такого понятия как Work Stealing.  Конечно, есть инструменты для анализа работы OpenMP программ, но они они обычно показывают результаты **разделения** общей работы между потоками. В то время как Stealing предполагает, что какой-то поток может выполнить работу, предназначенную изначально для другого потока.  Некоторые компиляторы, возможно, производят подобные действия для оптимизации производительности, но об этом лучше обратиться в службу поддержки конкретного компилятора. Например, в последней спецификации OpenMP 4.5 впервые явно упомянута возможность выполнения итераций цикла с нарушением их естественного порядка следования, так что, теоретичести, есть возможность применения Work Stealing алгоритмов.